# Combining count and linked tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `Clients` (`ID, name`), a table `Items1` (`ID, clientID, item1Name`) and a table `Items2` (`ID, ClientID, item2Name`)

`Clients`:

```
1, John
2, Miriam
3, Peter
4, Trude
```

`Items1`:

```
1,1,exam1
2,1,exam2
3,2,exam3
```

`Items2`:

```
1,1,test1
2,2,test2
3,4,test3
```

What I would like to accomplish is a query that sums up the `items1.ID` and the `items2.ID` together into one number, where the `clientID = n`

Query result

```
clientID, total Items
=====================
1,3
2,2
3,0
4,1
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You mean **count**, not **sum** - right?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this also works

```
SELECT c.id, 
       Count(item.itemname) AS TotalItem 
FROM   clients c 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, 
                         clientid, 
                         item1name AS itemName 
                  FROM   item1 
                  UNION ALL 
                  SELECT id, 
                         clientid, 
                         item2name AS itemName 
                  FROM   item2) item 
              ON c.id = item.clientid 
GROUP  BY c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select c.id, count(a.*) + count(b.*)
From clients a
Left join items1 a on c.id = a.clientid
Left join items2 b on c.id = b.clientid
Group by c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL-Server 2005 +

```
SELECT c.ID, i1.Cnt, i2.Cnt, i1.Cnt + i2.Cnt TotalCount
FROM Clients c
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) Cnt FROM Items1 WHERE ClientID = c.ID) i1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) Cnt FROM Items2 WHERE ClientID = c.ID) i2
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may help too:

```
;with CTE as
(select ClientID,count(*) as ItemsCount
 from Items1
 group by ClientID
 union all
 select ClientID,count(*)
 from Items2
 group by ClientID)
select c.ID,isnull(sum(CTE.ItemsCount),0)
from Clients c
left join CTE on c.ID=CTE.ClientID
group by c.ID
```